# To set default prefix value for input field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have `form` which consists of 2 fields called `countrycode` and `Phone Number`.

- My requirement is I want add `+` as default value in country code input field. Like this:

[image]

- And i should be able to send this prefix value(+), Along with the entered value in `country code` field.

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-vvmbnu?file=app/demo/demo.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
       name: [null,[Validators.required]],
       email: [null,[Validators.required]],
       counrtycode: ['+',[Validators.required]],
       phonenumber: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
```

Comment: You want the + prefix to be required or the whole field?
If you want a "PlusPrefixValidator" you can write your own CustomValidator